# comparing the times in a statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I want to compare on these times between `11:30PM` and `12:00AM` with `program_stop_time` that show the time `11:45PM` to see if I can get in the statement.

When I try this:

```
if program_stop_time > epg_time_1 and program_stop_time < epg_time_2:
    print "Now you are working on resize on the button"
```

It won't let me to get in the statement.

Here is the full code:

```
half_hour = str("11:30AM")
one_hour = str("12:00AM")
one_hour_half = str("12:30AM")
epg_time_1 = time.strptime(half_hour, '%I:%M%p')
epg_time_2 = time.strptime(one_hour, '%I:%M%p')
epg_time_3 = time.strptime(one_hour_half, '%I:%M%p')
stop_time = str("11:45PM")
program_stop_time = time.strptime(stop_time, '%I:%M%p')
program_stop_clock_list.append(program_stop_time)

if program_stop_time > epg_time_1 and program_stop_time < epg_time_2:
    print "Now you are working on resize on the button"
else:
    print "Now you are working on to remove the button"
```

Here is the `epg_time_1` time.struct_time:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=23, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Here is the `epg_time_2` time.struct_time:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

here is the `program_stop_time` time.struct_time:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=23, tm_min=45, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

I want to get in the statement if `epg_time_1` show the time `11:30PM` and `epg_time_2` show the time `12:00AM` when comparing with the `program_stop_time` that show the time `11:45PM`, so if `epg_time_1` show the time `12:00AM` which it come after the `program_stop_time` time `11:45PM` then I want to get in the else statement.

Can you please show me how I can do that using my code?

Comment: Is the first line supposed to be `half_hour = str("11:30PM")`? Not AM?

Comment: @gmoshkin [That's not entirely clear.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight)

Comment: @BradK. yes you are correct, i am using `half_hour = str("11:30PM")` as you can see it is a PM not AM. Can you show me an example how I can use a statement by using `if program_stop_time > epg_time_1 and program_stop_time < epg_time_2:` to compare the times?

Comment: @gmoshkin do you mean 12am is less than 11:30pm?

Comment: @SvenMarnach what do you mean? You want to say that the behavior of this code is undetermined?

Comment: @TimCullen no, I mean 12am is less than 11:30 am.

Comment: @gmoshkin ok so how do you write a statement like this `if program_stop_time > epg_time_1 and program_stop_time < epg_time_2:` to see if i can compare the times between `11:30PM` and `12:00AM`?

Comment: @TimCullen I can now see that 12AM is also less than 11:30PM, 12AM is the 0 second of the day and 11:30PM is 41400 second of the day. You should use `datetime` objects and specify the date, for the comparison to work.

Comment: Oh right, can you post the example code of what I should use instead of mine?

Comment: @gmoshkin What I mean is that there is confusion on whether 12am belongs to the previous day or the next day.  There doesn't even seem to be global agreement on whether it's midnight or noon.

Comment: you're right @SvenMarnach

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dates you are trying to use come occur across the 'day' boundary. So you want `11:30PM < 12:00AM < 12:30AM`, but in the way you specified them, they're all on the same day when converted to a `time` or `datetime` objects, so `12:00AM < 12:30AM < 11:30PM`. You can get around this by converting to `datetime` objects and adding one day to the AM times.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

half_hour = str("11:30PM")
one_hour = str("12:00AM")
one_hour_half = str("12:30AM")
epg_time_1 = datetime.strptime(half_hour, '%I:%M%p')
epg_time_2 = datetime.strptime(one_hour, '%I:%M%p')
epg_time_3 = datetime.strptime(one_hour_half, '%I:%M%p')
stop_time = str("11:45PM")
program_stop_time = datetime.strptime(stop_time, '%I:%M%p')
# program_stop_clock_list.append(program_stop_time)

epg_time_2 += timedelta(days=1)
epg_time_3 += timedelta(days=1)

if program_stop_time > epg_time_1 and program_stop_time < epg_time_2:
    print("Now you are working on resize on the button")
else:
    print("Now you are working on to remove the button")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you probably want ot change `11:30AM` to `11:30PM` in your code.

Secondly you should use `datetime` objects, because 12:00AM is the beginning of the day and 11:30PM is the end of the day, and you seem to be having problems with that.

```
import datetime

half_hour = str("1/1/1997 11:30PM")
one_hour = str("2/1/1997 12:00AM")
one_hour_half = str("12:30AM")
epg_time_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(half_hour, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
epg_time_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(one_hour, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
epg_time_3 = datetime.datetime.strptime(one_hour_half, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
stop_time = str("1/1/1997 11:45PM")
program_stop_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(stop_time, '%I:%M%p')

if program_stop_time > epg_time_1 and program_stop_time < epg_time_2:
    print "program_stop_time is between epg_time_1 and epg_time_2"
else:
    print "program_stop_time is NOT between epg_time_1 and epg_time_2"
```

Anyway the solution depends on data you have. If you can get the dates instead of just times as inputs to your program this solution suites you pretty good.